# UA through GTM macro: ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId') - ga is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Here is the site - http://www.ssangyong-favorit.ru/
For some reason this code is giving me "GA is not defined" error:

```
ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId')
```

This site has Google Analytics installed on it through GTM and it works and getting stats. The code works for any other site just fine.

The problem is that "ga" doesn't work for some reason and I can't understand why. Maybe it conflicts with something?

UA implemented normally (not Custom HTML).

Please, help me with figuring out what's going on and fixing it.

Comment: Don't link the site, link the corresponding code..I'm not going to shift through you're website code.

Comment: @Tony The code works. I have checked on many others sites with GA installed with GTM same way and it works there. It doesn't work on this site. So I'm assuming the reason is somewhere on it. If it is against the rules - ok I'll cut the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that you have renamed the ga object.

> ga_ckpr.getAll()[0].get('clientId')

in the javascript console returns a client id.

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me how did you figure it out? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: I typed "ga" in the console (using Chrome) to see if the proper object would be returned. Since the ga object was not present the console suggested various js variables that start with "ga", and when I choose to autocomplete with "ga_ckpr" the console returned the tracker object (this requires you to know that the object can be renamed - after that the diagnoses is rather simple).

Comment: Thanks! Good hint, now I have to find out which script changes "ga", but that is going to be another story.

Comment: Since the site uses Google Tag Manager I would assume that happens in GTM (look in the GA tag, Advanced Configuration, Global Function Name - at least in v1, probably called differently in the new interface).